# C++ templates to access arrays of different element size?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

How do I use C++ templates to accomplish the following, or is there some better method?

My pgm contains a number of large, simple tables. To save space, each table can be char, short, long or long long (i e, entries with 8, 16, 32 or 64 bits in my compiler, VS2010), depending on the table contents (the tables are built once at the beginning of the pgm). I have functions that operate on these tables, and I'd like to write a single function that handles all the types.

The tables are allocated using new. A simplified version for illustration:

```
struct S1 {char x;}
struct S2 {short x;};
struct S4 {long x;}
struct S8 {long long x;};
struct V {int n; void *v}; // n=1,2,4 or 8, and v points to an array of Sn

V.v=new Sn[arrayLength]; // Sn is one of S1, S2, S4 or S8
```

The problem comes when I want to access an array element using v[i], because the array element size is unknown at compile time. It seems as if templates should allow this to be done, but I have no experience with them.

To elaborate, incorporating Crazy Eddie's suggestion, my code now looks like

In VA.h:

```
class VA
{
    struct S1 {char x;}
    struct S2 {short x;};
    struct S4 {long x;}
    struct S8 {long long x;};
    template < typename T>
    struct V {int n; T *v}; // n=1,2,4 or 8, and v points to an array of Sn

    V vTable[1000]; // a fixed array size

    void Func1(int k, int n, int size);
};
```

In VA.cpp:

```
void Func1(int k, int n, int size)
{
    V<T> *pV=&vTable[k]; // Question 1: How do I get from n to the appropriate type T?
    pV->n=n;
    pV->v=new SOMETHING[size]; // Question 2: What should SOMETHING be here?
                               // I am allocating an array of Sn
    ...
```

Comment: Consider using the <vector> library

Answer (score 2):

No, templates won't help solve the problem you've created by using `void*`.  Type information is gone.  The compiler only knows the `void*` and has zero knowledge of the size of the component behind it.

If, on the other hand, you'd used templates to begin with you'd not be having this problem:

```
template < typename T >
struct V { int n; T * v; };
```

Comment: This looks like what I want. Can you elaborate a little? If I now want a function in the class containing V, how do I pass it the actual type name? And what is the syntax for the "new" allocation?

Comment: This wouldn't allow him to have a single structure to hold all of the different structures though...

Comment: With that definition, you can use `V<S2>` etc. as types.  You can also write template functions whose declarations begin with `template<typename T>` that do things with general `V<T>` objects.

Comment: See additional details and questions added to my initial post

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own template, why not use a template library?

The [Boost::Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html) or [Boost::Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/any.html) might help you here. They were designed for specifically the kind of problem that you have.

See: [boost::variant conversion to type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539573/boostvariant-conversion-to-type)

Comment: Although I didn't mention it, speed is also important. I suspect the template library is much less efficient than custom C++ code.

Comment: @Woody20: No, often the standard library's template functions are just as fast as custom code, or better.

Comment: @Woody20: It's not a regular library, it's a template library! Objects created out of templates are specifically tailored for the types that were specified, hence they are space and time efficient, compared to if templates were not used. Boost libraries are also peer-reviewed before inclusion. Also, for your case, if you, for example, sum all the array elements together and want to print them out, you need to know whether to use "%c" or "%d" or "%lu" modifier for printf. So, it needs to be tailored to the specific type. For this, Boost::Variant's visitor interface is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'll be better server by writing a 'primitive' container..(or even use a standard one.)
If writing yourself, the design of std::array is what you should seek to copy, unless you need the size to be dynamic.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
class array
{
public:
    //....Constructors..etc
private:
    T* data;
}
```

Also, consider implementing iterators, sounds like a lot of your functions will be simpler to implement that way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirements correctly, you may want to look into the vector library. E.g:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<char> V;
```

V is now a dynamic list whose elements are 1 char wide each.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the updated questions:

1. You use a switch:

> ```
> template<typename Sn>
> void Func1(int k, int size)
> {
>     V<Sn> *pV=&vTable<Sn>[k];
>     // No need for pv->n; just call sizeof(T).
>     pV->v=new Sn[size];
> }
>
> void Func1(int k, int n, int size)
> {
>   switch (n) {
>     case 1: Func1<S1>(k, size);
>     case 2: Func1<S2>(k, size);
>     // ...
>   }
> }
> ```

Mind you, when you know `n` at compile time, you can call Func1 directly. Also,
be aware that `V` is a class template, not a class. `V<S1>` is a class. You therefore cannot have an array of `V`'s, but you can have an array of `V<S1>`.

Comment: MSalters, in your answer, your "template void Func1" has no indication to the compiler what the template class or type is. What am I missing? And I don't see how the "new Sn" will be replaced by "new S1", "new S2", etc (there is no type "Sn"; it was just my shorthand for "one of the S's").

Answer (score -1):

What you could do instead is use a union.

Do something like so

```
union unionType {
  char a;
  int b;
  long long c;
};
```

Now this will allow you to just specify the array type as the union. The problem with this is you may wind up with a bunch of wasted memory because of padding that is inserted by the union. You may also have to do something like so to keep track of the type:

```
struct arrayType {
   int type; //Something like 0-char, 1-short, 2-long, etc...
   unionType value;
};

struct arrayType {
  int length;
  arrayType v;
}
```

For more information on unions I actually quite like the wikipedia page on them: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type

Comment: -1 He specifically said he does it to save space, and your solution wastes it.

Comment: I offer it simply as a way to do this without using external libraries such as boost.

Comment: There's no need for external libraries, see Crazy Eddie's answer.

Comment: Kleist is correct. These tables are huge, and the only point of the varying type is to save space.